# Snakemake: Zip option in expand not working

Tags: python, snakemake

I am using expand and glob_wildcards in my snakamake script. I have two subdirectories in my directoty libraries with fastq forward and reverse files structured like follows :

```
libraries:
    - MMETSP1:
           - SRR19_1
           - SRR19_2
    - MMETSP2:
          - SRR20_1
          - SRR20_2
```

I am obtaining all the combinations possible in the two directories with the **zip option of expand**. But what i wanted is just a list of the forward files with comma seperated (ex: SRR19_1, SRR20_1) and and so for the reverse files (ex: SRR19_2, SRR20_2).

And when i remove the zip option ia have this error:

```
MissingInputException in line 159 of /projet/fr2424/sib/gniang/script/snakemake/scripts/dntap_test.py:
Missing input files for rule trinity:
/projet/fr2424/sib/gniang/script/snakemake/libraries/MMESTP1/SRR1300320_1.fastq.gz
/projet/fr2424/sib/gniang/script/snakemake/libraries/MMESTP1/SRR1300320_2.fastq.gz
/projet/fr2424/sib/gniang/script/snakemake/libraries/MMETSP2/SRR1300319_2.fastq.gz
/projet/fr2424/sib/gniang/script/snakemake/libraries/MMETSP2/SRR1300319_1.fastq.gz
```

I am using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#  Imports
import os
import glob
import sys

# Get current working directory
dir_path = os.getcwd()

# User defined ouput directory
OUT_DIR = config["directories"]["outdir"]

#  User defined input directory
LIBRARY_DIR = config["directories"]["libraries"]

# Relative output directories
TRINITY_DIR = OUT_DIR + "trinity_out"

# Wildcards for input files
(LIBRARY, FASTQ, SENS) = glob_wildcards(LIBRARY_DIR + "{mmetsp}/{reads}_{type}.fastq.gz")


# ALL
rule all:
    input:
        trinity_out = TRINITY_DIR + "/Trinity.fasta",
        forward = directory(TRIMMOMATIC_DIR + "/forward.trimmomatic.paired.fastq"),
        reverse = directory(TRIMMOMATIC_DIR + "/reverse.trimmomatic.paired.fastq")

# TRINITY: This rule is use to de novo assemble filtered FASTQ files into
# contigs.
rule trinity:
    input:
        forward = expand(LIBRARY_DIR + "{mmetsp}" + "/" + "{reads}_1.fastq.gz", mmetsp=LIBRARY, reads=FASTQ),
        reverse = expand(LIBRARY_DIR + "{mmetsp}" + "/" + "{reads}_2.fastq.gz", mmetsp=LIBRARY, reads=FASTQ),
    output:
        trinity_out = TRINITY_DIR + "/Trinity.fasta",
        forward = directory(TRIMMOMATIC_DIR + "/forward.trimmomatic.paired.fastq"),
        reverse = directory(TRIMMOMATIC_DIR + "/reverse.trimmomatic.paired.fastq"),
    log:
        OUT_DIR + "logs/trinity/trinity.log"
    params:
        max_memory = config["trinity_params"]["max_memory"],
        trinity_dir = directory(TRINITY_DIR),
        trimmomatic_out = directory(TRIMMOMATIC_DIR),
        trimmomatic_params = config["trimmomatic_params"],
        illumina_adaptor = config["samples"]["illumina_adaptor"],
    threads:
        config["threads"]["trinity"]
    run:

        shell("""

        {trinity} \
        --seqType fq \
        --left {input.forward}  \
        --right {input.reverse} \
        --trimmomatic \
        --quality_trimming_params "ILLUMINACLIP:{params.illumina_adaptor}:2:30:10 {params.trimmomatic_params}" \
        --normalize_reads \
        --normalize_by_read_set \
        --output {params.trinity_dir} \
        --CPU {threads} \
        --output {params.trinity_dir} \
        --CPU {threads} \
        --max_memory {params.max_memory} > {log}

        mkdir -p {params.trimmomatic_out}
        mkdir -p {params.trimmomatic_out}/forward.trimmomatic.paired.fastq
        mkdir -p {params.trimmomatic_out}/forward.trimmomatic.paired.fastq
        mkdir -p {params.trimmomatic_out}/forward.trimmomatic.unpaired.fastq
        mkdir -p {params.trimmomatic_out}/reverse.trimmomatic.unpaired.fastq

        mv {params.trinity_dir}/*P.qtrim.gz {output.forward}
        mv {params.trinity_dir}/*P.qtrim.gz {output.reverse}
        mv {params.trinity_dir}/*U.qtrim.fq {params.trimmomatic_out}/forward.trimmomatic.unpaired.fastq
        mv {params.trinity_dir}/*U.qtrim.fq {params.trimmomatic_out}/reverse.trimmomatic.unpaired.fastq
        """)
```

Can someone help me please.

Comment: I would suggest to post a minimal code that shows your problem. Your current example code is way too long.

Comment: Ok i will do that

Comment: Perhaps you could writing a python function to get lists of forward and reverse files? That might make things simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. i have used python glob to create a list of reverse and forward files and that worked perfectly. Thanks for your advise.  I wanted to kow if it is possible to use one library at sime to run the script and then use the other one. Which means if i want to run the script one with fastq files in library1 and at second time with the library two. Thanks in advance